# List with no indent?

Tags: html, css, indentation

I came accross this fiddle, I would like the 2.1 to have NO INDENT. Please see below some code I got from someone else, works like a charm but I dont want the indents!
Any ideas? If anyone can assist it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

the code:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
  
    margin:0;
   
    
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
        <ol>
            <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
            <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
        <ol>
            <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
            <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `display: table` and `display:table-cell` from your CSS.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
        <ol>
            <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
            <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
        <ol>
            <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
            <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

if you want all text to stay on the same level, the only workaround i came up with is to set fixed width to the `li:before`

see snippet >

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 40px;
}

li li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
        <ol>
            <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
            <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
        <ol>
            <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
            <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
                <ol>
                    <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @Jan-HendrikKruger glad i could help. don't forget to rate/accept my answer :d thanks !

Comment: Thanks will do, im stuck again as I want no indents at all but also keep the allignment neat like in your sample...

Comment: if you want all text to stay on the same level, the only workaround i came up with is to set fixed width to the `li:before` see my updated answer

Comment: yes I see, it works but as soon as text becomes more, the allignment is not in place...

Comment: ok I fixed it by adding your previous code:

ol > li > ol > li li:before {   display: table-cell;}