# Aligning `counter(item)` for nested `ol`

Tags: html, css

I have nested a few `ol` and am using `counter(item)` to style the list items. The top-level `ol` has the standard decimal, while the `ol ol > li:before` is styled with `content: counter(item,lower-roman) ". ";`

When I do this, the inner list items have weird indentation, since the `li:before` have different widths (`i.`, vs `ii.`, `iii.`, etc.)

How can I align the text of the inner lists?

https://jsfiddle.net/k1s2j3ps/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List with no indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109394/list-with-no-indent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a `min-width` on the counter, something like:

```
ol ol > li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    min-width: 20px; /* <--- */
    display: inline-block; /* <--- */
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol > li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
ol ol {
  font-size: 1em;
}
ol ol > li:before {
  content: counter(item,lower-roman) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  min-width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>That</li>
  <li>
    A description of the list to follow:
    <ol>
      <li>text</li>
      <li>indented</li>
      <li>within</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109394/list-with-no-indent), credits to the OP

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
  
    margin:0;
   
    
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
        <ol>
            <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
            <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
        <ol>
            <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
            <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi.</li>
</ol>
```